Relationship Between Ground State Wavefunctions' Amplitudes Under Discrete Symmetry Operations
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}$
Given a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ and a discrete symmetry $\hat{T}$, it's known that $\hat{T}\ket{\psi_{GS}}$, where $\ket{\psi_{GS}}=\sum_\sigma \psi_{GS}(\sigma)\ket{\sigma}$ is the ground state to $\hat{H}$, is also a ground state. I came across one paper stating that $\psi_{GS}(\hat{T}\sigma)=\omega_T\psi(\sigma)$, where $\omega_T$ is the eigenvalue for $\ket{\psi_{GS}}$, i.e. $\hat{T}\ket{\psi_{GS}}=\omega_T\ket{\psi_{GS}}$. I have difficulty proving this claim. My current attempt is $\hat{T}\ket{\psi_{GS}}=\sum_\sigma \psi_{GS}(\sigma)\hat{T}\ket{\sigma}=\sum_{\sigma'} \psi_{GS}(\hat{T}^\dagger\sigma')\ket{\sigma'}=\sum_\sigma \omega_T\psi_{GS}(\sigma)\ket{\sigma}\rightarrow \psi_{GS}(\hat{T}^\dagger\sigma)=\omega_T\psi(\sigma)$, which is not quite there. Could some please correct any place I possibly made mistakes?

I think that you are correct in what you have.
The authors of your paper have defined the action of $\hat T$ on the states $|\sigma\rangle$ but it is not clear what they  mean by $\psi(\hat T \sigma)$ as  $\sigma$ is simply a label on the basis states, and not itself a state.  Consequently  $\hat T$ does not act on $\sigma$. Given that it is not yet defined we may   define a map $T$ (no hat, and there is no sense in which $T$ is a linear map)) acting on the label set  by  requiring that
$$
\hat T \left(\sum_\sigma \psi(\sigma) |\sigma\rangle\right) = \sum_\sigma \psi(T^{-1} \sigma)|\sigma \rangle.
$$
Note that, as you have found,  the inverse $T^{-1}$ is required for proper composition of maps:
$$
\hat S\hat T\left(\sum_\sigma \psi(\sigma) |\sigma\rangle\right) = \hat S\left(\sum_\sigma \psi(T^{-1} \sigma)|\sigma \rangle\right)\\
= \sum_\sigma \psi(T^{-1} (S^{-1}\sigma))|\sigma \rangle\\
= \sum_\sigma \psi((ST)^{-1} \sigma)|\sigma \rangle.
$$
This is just as  the action of a translation of a function through $a$ takes $\psi(x)$ to $\psi(x-a)$.
Perhaps the authors of the original paper tacitly assume that $\hat T^2= {\rm id}$?
